# How to test my http request in my app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am trying to write units test for my app and I have the following issue

In my controller, I have something like

```
 $scope.test1 = function() {
     productFactory.getName()
         .then(function(products){
             $scope.result = products;
          })
}
```

productFactory

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('productFactory', function($http) {
    var factoryObj = {};
    factoryObj.getName = function() {
        return http.get(url)
    }

    return factoryObj
})
```

In my unit test file

```
describe('test here', function () {
    var testCtrl, scope, httpBackend, mockFactory;

    beforeEach(module('myApp', function($provide){
        $provide.value('productFactory', mockFactory);
    }));

    // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
    beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_, _$rootScope_, _$httpBackend_,  _productFactory_) {
        scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
        httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        mockFactory = _productFactory_;

        testCtrl = _$controller_('testCtrl', {
            $scope: scope
        });

    it('should get product name', function() {       
        scope.test1();
        //I am not sure how to test the results
    });
}));
```

When I run karma test, it gives me

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'productFactory.getName()')
```

I am not sure how to test the http result and fix the error. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Post the remaining code for the controller, it looks like you aren't injecting productFactory into the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to worry about using `$provide`:

```
beforeEach(module('myApp'));
```

**1. Without `$httpBackend` (mock out the service completely)**

Then, `productFactory` will be passed into your controller, but you want to `spyOn` the `getName()`:

```
// Initialize the controller and a mock scope
beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_, _$rootScope_, _$httpBackend_,  _productFactory_) {
    scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
    httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    mockFactory = _productFactory_;

    // add spy for the method, wrap with $q.when so it returns a promise
    spyOn(mockFactory, 'getName').and.returnValue($q.when('Pizza!'));

    testCtrl = _$controller_('testCtrl', {
        $scope: scope,
        productFactory: mockFactory  // pass in here
    });
```

Then, you've got to cause a `$digest` cycle, so that the promise will call through:

```
it('should get product name', function() {       
    scope.test1();

    // hit the $digest        
    scope.$apply();

    // expectation
    expect(scope.result).toBe('Pizza!')
});
```

**2. With `$httpBackend`**

```
// Initialize the controller and a mock scope
    beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_, _$rootScope_, _$httpBackend_) {
        scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
        httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;

        // set up httpBackent
        httpBackend.when('GET', '/products')
                            .respond([{ name: 'Pizza!'}, {name: 'Sandwich'}]);

        testCtrl = _$controller_('testCtrl', {
            $scope: scope
        });
```

We don't need to mock the factory in this case at all.  Then, we just need to `flush` `$httpBackend` when we want the http call to return:

```
it('should get product name', function() {       
    scope.test1();

    // hit the $digest with flush        
    httpBackend.flush();

    // expectation
    expect(scope.result.length).toBe(2)
});
```

Comment: It seems like this sort of thing would be better managed via `$httpBackend` expectations (e.g. `$httpBackend.expectGet(...).respond(200, 'Pizza!')`)  and then flushing.  As it is, (and if I read this properly), your spy manages to hide a bug in OP's original code (using `http` when they really meant `$http`)

Comment: @mgilson, Yes, you could be right.  `$httpBackend` might be better.  I've shown how to mock the service out completely from the controller.  If I was writing this app, I'd probably have tests that do both.

Comment: Thanks Davin it's very helpful. Would you please demo on how to write httpbackend as well? +1 Also, why don't I need $provide. I thought it's required to add factory?

Comment: @BonJon, @mgilson: example with `$httpBackend` added.